# Delayed_job(2.1.4) + Rails(3.0.10) undefined method `delay'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, nomethoderror

I upgrading a rails application to rails(3.0.10) and update the gem delayed_job. I updated my migration for the table delayed_job but unfortunatly the method ".delay" doesn't work.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `delay' for #<User:0x10394d140>
```

I didn't find a solution for that. I did : "bundle install", I restarted the server, tried to instal as plugin...

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

UPDATE :

I fixed the problem but created a file config/initializer/delayed_job.rb with

```
require 'delayed_job'
Delayed::Worker.backend = :active_record
```

Comment: i modified my answer in case you already read it

Comment: Just to ask the obvious, did you add delayed_job to your Gemfile?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sometimes gems just refuse to install properly. I think what you should do is (assuming you have git installed, otherwise go here https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job and download delayed_job as a zip file)

```
git clone https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job.git
```

take what he has in his lib folder and put it in yours. wherever you need to use his methods then do

```
require 'delayed_job'
```

in the top of those files

I checked this tutorial, it shows a way to setup in rails 3

```
http://www.dixis.com/?p=335
```

it suggests using this in your gemfile

```
gem "delayed_job",  :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git'
```

(if it doesn't work with this either, then try the same thing that i did, but replace

```
git clone https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job.git
```

with

```
git clone https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git
```

tell me if anything works

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I think my problem is because I upgrade to rails 3 and we used the previous version of the gem with "send_later".

So for the moment it don't work, and I don't know what is the problem.

Thanks again

Comment: I fixed the problem but created a file config/initializer/delayed_job.rb with


require 'delayed_job'
Delayed::Worker.backend = :active_record